# How do I insert space before capital letter if and only if previous letter is not capital?

Tags: python, regex

I have the text:

```
'SMThingAnotherThingBIGCapitalLetters'
```

and I want the output to be:

```
'SM Thing Another Thing BIG Capital Letters'
```

My regex now:

```
r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2"
```

This works when I don't have 2 capital letters near eachother.

Output for my regex:

```
'S MThing Another Thing B I G Capital Letters'
```

So, I need regex to insert a space before a capital letter when next letter is small.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: `r"([^A-Z])([A-Z])", r"\1 \2"`? Or, `r"([^\WA-Z])([A-Z])", r"\1 \2"`?

Comment: Must you use regular expressions?  A simple text loop might be easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: How about [`\B(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])\B(?=[A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/PfEC3K/1/) and replace with space.

Comment: Considering **I need regex to insert a space before a capital letter when next letter is small** your actual goal, `SMThingAnotherThingBIGCapitalLetters` is going to be: `SM Thing Another ThingBIG Capital Letters`. Is that your goal?

Comment: Moreover, your title is inconsistent with the content of your question. Do you mean: *How do I insert space before capital letter if and only if next letter is not capital?*

Comment: Why a space before `Thing`? The letter before **IS** a capital (i.e. `M`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use regular expressions carefully. They can easily transform to gargantuan monsters nobody can understand. You can solve your problem with simple loop instead of regexp:

```
a = 'SMThingAnotherThingBIGCapitalLetters'
result = a[0]

for i, letter in enumerate(a):
    if letter.isupper() and (result[-1].islower() or a[i+1].islower()):
        result += ' '
    if i: result += letter
result
```

> `'SM Thing Another Thing BIG Capital Letters'`

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about `.isupper/islower()`! Simplified the code.

Comment: OP talks about *insert a space before a capital letter when next letter is small*. Then, why `Thing BIG`?

Comment: Just look at OPs _and I want the output to be:_ string. It is equal to mine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use alternation with 2 capturing groups and replace with `group1 group2 space` like `r"\1\2 "`

```
([A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|([a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

**Explanation**

- `([A-Z])` Capture captital A-Z in group 1
- `(?=[A-Z][a-z])` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is an uppercase and a lowercase a-z
- `|` Or
- `([a-z])` Capture lowercase a-z in group 2
- `(?=[A-Z])` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is uppercase A-Z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vMTfvH/1)